# MATLAB Image Analysis

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to analyse a picture of some wires embedded in a rubber casing and find the distance between the wires and the edge (image attached).

I have converted the image into binary for ease of computation

[image]

To achieve this I plan to cycle through the image horizontally analysing each row and detecting all the non-black pixels and storing them in a 1xN matrix. At the end of the image I want to concatenate this matrix so it gives a histogram of the number of white pixels along each row and the space between the peaks (after a certain threshold) will indicate the pixel spacing.

My code at the moment is as follows but I'm limited in my programming capability.

```
my_image =imread('image');
for R=1:n
    for C=1:n
        pixel=my_image(R,C);
        if pixel==1 
            counter=counter+1;
        end
   counter
    end
    counter=0;
end
```

Comment: Hi - what is the problem - can you explain what the question is and what sort of results/errors you are getting at the moment

Comment: So, are straight and long lines edges and the angled lines wires, and you want to find the distance between edge and wire? Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to compute the total number of white pixels per row and we'll store this in an array.  The code that you have almost works.  What you are doing though is counting the **total** amount of white pixels overall in your image.  This code does not describe your desired behaviour exactly.

As such, let's go ahead and do this correctly.  After this, we can then provide a [`stem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html) plot where we can use the X-axis to index the row number of your image while the Y-axis can be used to display the total number of white pixels that are seen in the image.  This is pretty much for your own observation, but let's go ahead and plot this:

```
im = imread('http://i.imgur.com/lc8ESac.png'); %// Read in from your post
imBinary = double(im2bw(im)); %// Just in case - Convert to binary, 
                              %// then make double for sum
histogram = sum(imBinary,2); %// Compute row-wise histograms
stem(1:size(imBinary,1), histogram); %// Plot this histogram
xlabel('Row number');
ylabel('White pixel count');
grid;
```

[image]

As you can see from the image, this agrees with your logic.  You'll see that approximately around rows 150 to 225, there are spikes in the histogram.  If we were to take the difference between 225 and 150, this would give you the width (in pixels) of the wire.  However, where your logic will fail is in between approximately rows 300 to 400.  You'll see that the wires are on a **slant**.  If you were to sum along the rows, you would not be able to detect the thickness of these wires that way as you would only have a few pixels per row that are white.

---

If you want to ignore these, then we certainly can.  What you can do is use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to compute pairwise neighbouring distances between the elements.  Should any difference be non-zero, that means we will have detected a change.  All we would do is detect any changes, then threshold this difference so that anything larger than some number, those are the values we want to keep.  In other words, do this:

```
diffs = diff([0; histogram]);
threshold = 100; %// Define threshold here as per your request
rows = find(diffs >= threshold)

rows = 

148
217
475
```

How `diff` works is that for i<sup>th</sup> element in your array `x_i`, the output of `diff` `y_i` is such that:

```
y_i = x_{i+1} - x_i
```

Therefore, notice that in the `diff` call, I add a `0` at the beginning of the histogram before I do `diff` as we will assume that the first row consists entirely of zeroes and so the count should be 0.  I then determine which rows give me a pixel count of 100 or more.  This is a user-defined threshold that I made up.

Once we do this, we can then use another `diff` command to find the final thickness in between the wires:

```
thickness = diff(rows)

thickness =

  69
 258
```

This says that you have one wire with a thickness of 69 pixels, while the next wire after that has a thickness of 258 pixels.

This is obviously very sensitive to your threshold and the way you binarize your image, but this should be enough to get you started.

---

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the clarification it is definately the direction that this little project was going to. I had trouble finding a way to store the number of pixels in each row (initially wanted to store it in a 1xN array) but this is very valid as well.